# Trigonometry, eliminate theta

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve this problem quite for a while but this was all in vain

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the equations: 
>   $$x = \sin \theta + \tan \theta, y = \sin \theta - \tan \theta$$

Please help solving this problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! T.Bongers has edited your post to include mathjax formatting; please make sure it says what you intended. Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried?

Comment: with all your help I had my problem solved.
working:
x+y/2 = sin teta ---- cosec teta = 2/x+y
x-y/2 = tan teta ----- cot teta = 2/x-y
from cosec^2teta=1+cot^2teta
4/(x+y)^2 = 1 + 4/ (x-y)^2

thanks

Comment: @chaya The formula you give falls into problems when $x+y=0$ or $x-y=0$, i.e. when $\sin\theta =0$ or $\theta = \pi n$. The correct expression is $x^4-2x^2y^2+16xy+y^4=0$. Remember to click the upward arrows next to answers that you found helpful and to click the tick next to the one you found most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

1. Notice that $x+y=2\sin\theta$ and $x-y=2\tan\theta$.
2. Recall that $\tan\theta\equiv\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$
3. Recall that $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta \equiv 1$
4. Consider $(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$ in terms of $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Solve for $\displaystyle \tan\theta,\sin\theta$

$\text{As }\displaystyle \csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta=1,$

use $\displaystyle \frac1{(\sin\theta)^2}-\frac1{(\tan\theta)^2}=1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ and also $(x-y)=2\tan\theta$ and $(x+y)=2\sin\theta$.

Therefore, $$\begin{align}x^2-y^2&=2\tan\theta\cdot2\sin\theta\\\therefore(x^2-y^2)^2&=16\tan^2\theta\sin^2\theta\\&=16(\sec^2\theta-1)(\sin^2\theta)\\&=16(\tan^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\\&=16(\tan\theta+\sin\theta)(\tan\theta-\sin\theta)\\&=-16xy\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{cases}x+y=2\sin\theta\\x-y=2\tan\theta\end{cases}\implies \theta=\arcsin\frac{x+y}2=\arctan\frac{x-y}2=\arcsin\frac t{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$

with

$$\;t=\frac{x-y}2\;\implies t^2+1=\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{4}+1\implies$$

$$\frac t{\sqrt{t^2+1}}=\frac{(x-y)}{\sqrt{x^2-2xy+y^2+4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equations simultaneously to get $\sin\theta = \frac{x+y}2$ and
$\tan \theta = \frac{x-y}2$

$\tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$

Substitute value of $\sin \theta$ and $\tan \theta$ to get $\cos \theta = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$

Finally $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Finally substitute the values of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos \theta$ to get the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer should be 
$-16 xy = ( x ^ 2 - y ^2 ) ^2$.
\begin{align}
\tan \theta &=  \frac{x - y}2\\
\sin \theta &= \frac{x+y}2
\end{align}
Use $\operatorname{cosec}^2 \theta - \cot ^2 \theta = 1$ 
to find the answer.
It is $\frac4{(x + y)^2} - \frac4{(x - y)^2} = 1$
We get
         $$- 16 xy = (x^2 -y^2)^2$$
Problem solved

Comment: I am also using x instead of theta as I do not know how to type theta in a computer.  so tan x  means tan theta

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: BTW it is never good idea to use the same symbol for two different things. Like $x$ to mean both $x$ and $\theta$. I hope I have replaced $x$ by $\theta$ in correct places.